# Unknown javascript function declaration pattern

Tags: javascript

I have never seen this design pattern before, what is it doing?

```
(function(def){
    if(typeof module!='undefined'){
        module.exports=def;
    }
    else{
        this.nut=def;
    }
}( function(){
   ...
}() ));
```

Comment: Passing one anonymous function into another.

Comment: Are you asking why a function is passed to the other function, or how the whole construct (`(function(foo) {...}(bar))`) works? Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript.

Comment: Seems like an overly complicated way to make a module that falls back to being a global in environments without CommonJS module support.

Comment: @FelixKling I am asking why, I don't see why you can't just define a function like normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a "immediately invoked function expression", as Ben Alman would say. The first function defined takes one argument, `def`. Wrapping this function in parantheses and passing it a second function definition (also in parentheses) immediately invokes the first function, passing it the result of the second function (it is also immediately invoked) as the `def` parameter.

More information: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Answer (score 1):

lets decode it step by step

```
function(def)
{
    if(typeof module!='undefined'){
        module.exports=def;
    }
    else{
        this.nut=def;
    }
}( function(){}());
```

//the outer brackets removed
now as u can see a function is defined which is a normal way to define a function
which takes one argument `def`
immediately after the definition there is a bracket
so if we breakit down further then

```
function(def) //function 1
    {
        if(typeof module!='undefined'){
            module.exports=def;
        }
        else{
            this.nut=def;
        }
    }( function() /*function 2*/{}());
```

this simply means that second function is passed as a parameter to the first function
a `bracket ()` just after the definition of a function in JS signifies that that function here `function 1` will be call immediately after the definition. and what ever is inside the brackets will be passed to the function as parameter so `def` basically is `function2`